# Verilog task with packed struct argument

Tags: task, verilog, system-verilog, procedure

I have an issue with a SystemVerilog task which performs parallel bus reads and writes.  It uses a packed struct ref argument.   The task does not compile.

I have a struct that contains all the signals for a bus

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic clk;
  logic rst;
  logic [31:0] addr;
  logic read;
  logic write;
  logic [31:0] write_data;
  logic [31:0] read_data;
  logic read_data_valid;
} sv_lb_type
```

Then I want to write a procedure/task to do a write. Something like this:

```
task automatic lb_write(
    input [31:0]   writeAddr,
    input [31:0]   writeData,
    ref struct {
      logic clk;
      logic rst;
      logic [31:0] addr;
      logic read;
      logic write;
      logic [31:0] write_data;
      logic [31:0] read_data;
      logic read_data_valid;
    } lb
  );
    begin

      $display("Waiting for LB reset to be deasserted");
      while (lb.rst != 1'b0) begin
        @(posedge lb.clk);
      end
      
      @(posedge lb.clk);
      
      lb.read       = 1'b1;
      lb.write      = 1'b0;
      lb.addr       = writeAddr;
      lb.write_data = writeData;
      
      @(posedge lb.clk);
      
      lb.read       = 1'b0;
      lb.write      = 1'b0;
      lb.addr       = '0;
      lb.write_data = '0;
      
      @(posedge lb.clk);
    
    end
  endtask
```

The very simplified testbench looks like this:

```
`timescale  1 ps / 1 ps
`include "svInterfaces.sv"

module tb ( );
  import simMainPackage::*;
  
  wire                               rfClk;
  wire                               rfRst;
  
  // Local bus interface
  wire sv_lb_type                    lb_ds;

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Testbench clock and reset generation
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  clock_gen #(
    .FREQ   (100000)
  ) rfClk_inst (
    .enable (1'b1),
    .clk    (rfClk),
    .rst    (rfRst)
  );

  assign lb_ds.clk = rfClk;
  assign lb_ds.rst = rfRst;
  

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // DUT
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  model_runner # (
      .ADDRESS                    (0)
    ) dut_inst (
      .clk                        (rfClk),
      .rst                        (rfRst),

      // Local bus interface
      .lb_us                      (lb_ds)
    );

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Driving Process
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  task run();
    $display("Starting Simulation");
    
    #10
    
    @(posedge lb_ds.clk);
    
    $display("Configuring Interface");
    lb_write(32'h00000001, 1, lb_ds);
    
    #10
    
    $stop();
  endtask


endmodule
```

But I can't find a way to write that task that doesn't just give me errors.

Comment: @Mikef I edited the original post to include a simplified test bench showing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: which error does it print? btw, why do you use ref struct instead of the defined typdef name?

Comment: @Serge the error depends on what I try. With the version above I get the error "Illegal value (lb_ds) for ref formal (lb).  Value must be assignable." from the test bench.

When I use the typedef name like this:

```
task automatic lb_write(
    input [31:0]   writeAddr,
    input [31:0]   writeData,
    ref sv_lb_type lb
  );
```
I get the error: near "lb": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ')'.

Comment: @annapCoug I think that your problem is in specifying the naked struct in declaration of the task. I have not checked the standard,  if this is allowed or not. probably not. You should use the name of the typedef instead: `ref sv_lb_type lb`

Comment: Why are you defining a struct inside a task? `ref struct {...} lb` should be `ref sv_lb_type lb`. Even though the struct elements and order are match, their type definition do not. Define your typedef once in a package and then reference your typedef.